# Is the turbopump outlet pressure higher or lower than the combustion chamber pressure?

Tags: rockets, pressure, turbopump, combustion-chamber

I always thought turbopump outlet pressure was higher, but when I asked chatGPT, it said the chamber pressure is higher in open cycle rocket engines. Now I am confused because how would that work if the liquids move from higher pressure to lower pressure. Wouldn’t that cause back flow and blow up some stuff? Thank you

Comment: Your intuition is right and ChatGPT is wrong as usual. If you trust it to give correct answers on technical matters, you will be disappointed. Spend a few minutes and look up some technical sources, you'll be better served. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTaou.jpg

Comment: ChatGPT is not a liar, it is a bullshitter. A liar consciously tries to convince you of something they know not to be true. A bullshitter, like ChatGPT, resembles the drunk at the end of the bar: it just blathers on, spouting superficially plausible nonsense. It never bothers to fact check anything it says. It has no access to information less than a year old. Artificial, yes. Intelligence? Hardly.

Comment: Duplicate of [Overcoming pressure differential to feed fuel into rocket engines](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19647/overcoming-pressure-differential-to-feed-fuel-into-rocket-engines)