# Single shaft turbopump vs two turbopumps

Tags: rockets, engines, turbopump

What are the pros and cons of using same turbopump for fuel and oxidizer and using 2 different pumps for both?

Comment: does this Q&A help?  https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34016/

Comment: It is not possible to use the same  turbopump for fuel and oxidizer for all propellants that could be mixed only in the combustion chamber.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean having fuel and oxidizer turbopumps on the same shaft, powered by a single turbine, as opposed to two shafts, each with its own turbine?