# Full Flow Staged Combustion Benefits vs Closed Staged Combustion

Tags: rockets, engines, ssme, raptor

I am aware that the RS-25 space shuttle engine was a closed staged combustion engine, and used two preburners (both fuel rich) to drive the turbines and pumps to pump the LOX and fuel into the combustion chamber. I am also aware that a full-flow staged combustion engine (like the Raptor) uses two seperate turbines, similarly, but instead, uses a LOX rich and a fuel rich preburner. From an engine efficiency/ architecture perspective, what is the benefit of having full flow rather than just having two fuel rich preburners?

Comment: some helpful information might be found in the video in [Rocket Engine Plumbing: Still don't understand the Full Flow Staged Combustion Cycle](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18538/12102) and in answers there.